# What is the appropriate here linear layout or relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-relativelayout

Please check attached screenshot, its simple layout to design in which I want to keep progress bar and two text view at center. I have used linear layout as the parent and set layout gravity as center, with this I expect that all of the views should be center along with linearly. XML Graphical preview gives expected output however if I flash the same to the device, there will be a gap in the bottom. I am trying to understanding what could be the reason, Can you help me what is wrong in this design? should i have to consider relative layout in this context, why I am not able to achieve this through Linear layout?

Here is the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_progress"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/reg_dimen_12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sync_data_title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reg_dimen_24dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/sync_data_desc"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the layout which i am trying

[image]

On the device, it looks as below,

[image]

Comment: show your xml code

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: can you add your layout file

Comment: Hi @Niranj Patel, please find XML code

Comment: post your drawable bg_progress used in linearlayout

Comment: Hi @aman5319, resolution of the image is 1440*2560 , xxx-hdpi

Comment: can you post xxhdpi image ?

Comment: Hi @NiranjPatel , i have only one resolution image maintained in xxx-hdpi folder , which is of size 1440 × 2560, i don't have xxhdpi image .

Comment: I can suggest don't use high resolution image, it will increase APK size too, You can use shape drawable.

Comment: Hi @NiranjPatel, we have to plan to use svg images later, but it is not reason for this problem , right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to fix using `RelativeLayout`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_progress"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/reg_dimen_12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sync_data_title"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reg_dimen_24dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/sync_data_desc"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure it will resolved using RelativeLayout? and why not working with LinearLayout?

Comment: @NiranjPatel yes I had faced the same issue with linerlayout

Comment: That's the same question i have, why not with linearlayout . it works in RelativeLayout

Comment: @chethan I did too much research on this but I could not find why linerlayout behaving weirdly

Comment: @MilanPansuriya, it's ok, I appreciate your time, but i knew one thing that , view which we have inside doesn't have size defined, progressbar , textview are defined with wrap content . so system doesn't know its size to place it properly, that could be the reason for this inappropriate. that's what my understanding,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shape drawable instead large Image as background.

Here is sample Shape for your background and use it in background of LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#EB7C97"
        android:startColor="#ED94A9"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi @Niranj Patel, but actually image is not the planned one, it is something else but it has same resolution of 1440*2560. i have removed that image to avoid posting that here.

Comment: still issue with shape drawable? not working then try with color, if still not work with background color then must be problem is else

Comment: Is it activity or fragment?

Comment: issue is still there, i tried with above shape drawable . now only 1/3 rd of screen is presenting . this is really tricky

Comment: Its only fragment

Comment: Ohh I see, can you show xml code of main activity where you replacing this layout

Comment: I think your FrameLayout's height is wrap_content where you replacing fragment, make it match_parent and check

Comment: Please check this link for xml code of main activity - https://jumpshare.com/v/IvMVg7aOmLYKRM7EtT6X

Fragments are loading on frame_container

Comment: I think is not correct one, show me layout where you replacing fragment

Comment: Fragments are replaced on linearlayout which you can find on shared link, the ID of that says frame_container . All other fragments with there layouts are fitting properly, they all coming in full screen as it is expected .  is that layout working at your end ?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_progress">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/reg_dimen_12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sync_data_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reg_dimen_24dp"
            android:text="@string/sync_data_desc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: of-curse this will work . but what is the understanding on my post and why the LinearLayout Or RelativeLayout is not behaving as we expected ?